# MySQL change column data type with converting rule

Tags: mysql, datetime, type-conversion, integer, sqldatatypes

I have a column with int, That only included year. I want to change its data type to DATETIME, with converting(for example, 2022 will be converted to 2022-01-01).
Is any way to converting it without losing data?

Comment: By converting it, do you mean selecting a date?  Or actually changing what's stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is `t` and you the `INT` is `yr` and you want to rename the column at the same time, to `dt`:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN dt DATETYPE NOT NULL;
UPDATE t SET dt = CONCAT(yr, '01-01');
ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN yr;
```

(Note that there is also a datatype "YEAR".)

What can go wrong?  `DATETIME` may have limits on what value the year can be.  Give this a try:

```
SELECT MIN(CONCAT(yr, '01-01'), MAX(CONCAT(yr, '01-01'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I know YEAR exists, but I want new data will be datetime, and old data keeps least year.

Answer (score 1):

If all the current column values are just years, and you want to change the actual stored type to datetime, you would do:

```
update foo set bar=bar*10000+101;
alter table foo change bar bar datetime;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=03910ec450e6cde053183b5009c73eb1)

Comment: It seems another good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the pseudo

Convert numeric to string using CAST function. Example.

```
select cast ($year as CHAR) from tab
```

Further use STR_TO_DATE to convert the string to datetime. Example .

```
select str_to_date(cast($year as CHAR), format )from table
```

Comment: For completeness, please explain your steps.